# Is there a way of retrieving the type of a subclass, when an object is passed in as type super class?

Tags: java, oop

If I had a method signature

```
public void myMethod(SuperClass s){
}
```

and `SuperClass` has three subclasses, is there any way within `myMethod` I can get the class name of the subclass which was passed in?

Not sure if it's important, but SuperClass is abstract.

Comment: This may indicate a bad design. Why do you want to know this?

Answer (score 9):

> ***is there any way within myMethod I can get the class name of the subclass which was passed in?***

Yes, by using the [`getClass` method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29):

```
public void myMethod(SuperClass s){
    System.out.println(s.getClass());
}
```

---

**Remark 1:**

This does however sound to me like a Bad Design™.

Whatever you want to do in `myMethod` consider having a method for it in `SuperClass` (provide a meaningful default implementation, or make it abstract to force subclasses to implement the method) and call this method on `s` in your method:

```
public void myMethod(SuperClass s){
    s.abstractMethod();
}
```

**Remark 2:**

If `myMethod`s logic is seemingly unrelated to the purpose of the `SuperClass` and you don't want to put the `myMethod` code inside this class, consider implementing the [**visitor pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) instead.

Comment: Basically one of the subclass' has the meaning of termination (in the context of my design, for another class it interacts with). Therefore, I need to know when the 'termination' subclass has been passed into the method, as opposed to the other subclass types.

Comment: Add a `public boolean isTerminator() { return false; }` in `SuperClass` and override it to return `true` in the terminator class, then do `if (s.isTerminator())` in `myMethod`.